# Unable to select<Div> dropdown in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t8fb.png)

HTML For the page

```
<a id="navigation.batch" Class="more" href="../../../ratingbatch/summary">
<div Class="nested">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
   <a id="id3" href="../../../ratingbatch/summary">Summary</a>
   <a id="id4" href="../../../ratingbatch/search">Search</a>
```

For the above dropdown menu I am unable to select Menu as well as dropdown links
Tried all most all the options online but nothing seems to be working.
I am getting all the time null pointer exception error.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

My code is as below:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement mnuElement;
        mnuElement  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        // Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
        builder.moveToElement(mnuElement).perform();
        // Giving 5 Secs for submenu to be displayed
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        // Clicking on the Hidden SubMenu
        driver.findElement(By.id("id4")).click();
```

Comment: where you have initilize the driver ?

Comment: Driver has been initialized in another method and I am using driver as global variable for different methods but all of them are in one single class  public void invoke_IE_and_navigate_to_the_application() throws Throwable {

Comment: Which line reports the null pointer exception?  Perhaps it is not finding the web element for the menu?  How did you determine the xpath?

Comment: Hi everyone Now I changed  the code  as below: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
     WebElement val = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")));
     val.click();    But Now I see below exception: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed

Comment: Add a click before you check for the visibility of the element. The element is not displayed because the element never appeared on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your drop-down menu is not open. So I will suggest you to do below things:

1. Click On drop-down control to open it.
2. Wait for list item to appear.
3. Then use code 
   `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("id4")),5,5).click().perform()`